# XAML Windows Phone 8.1 Button should change backgroundImage

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I know this kind of question have been asked a lot. But I couldn't solve it by my own.

The challenge to achieve is a simple button without any styling except a changing background image for several states (default, pressed and hover).

The code I've done so far is in my App.xaml file:

```
            <Style x:Key="likeActionButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="HoverBackground"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image Source="Assets/ActionsIcons/like-action.png"></Image>
                                    <Image x:Name="HoverBackground" Source="Assets/ActionsIcons/like-action-onHover.png" Visibility="Collapsed"></Image>
                                    <Image x:Name="PressedBackground" Source="Assets/ActionsIcons/like-action-on-pressed.png" Visibility="Collapsed"></Image>
                                </Grid>        
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

[Calling the button style from somewhere]

```
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource likeActionButton}"/>
```

So this XAML code seems to do nothing because there is no image at all..

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: It is unclear if the button style is found on the page with the button. I suggest you move it out of the app.xaml and put it with the button on that page. Also run the program in debug mode and monitor the output window...you may see binding issues or other items of xaml failures.

Comment: Path you given to source is wrong add ms-appx:/// to the path
Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ActionsIcons/like-action.png"

Comment: @OmegaMan The output window doesnt show any errors or warnings. And the movement of the XAML code to the current page didn't work as well.
@Archana I really thought this could be it but still the buttons aren't there.

I've tried to add a background property to make the button at least somehow visibile. I don't understand why this is also not working?
` <Button Background="LightSeaGreen" Style="{StaticResource likeActionButton}"></Button>`

Comment: OK. I've managed to make the button visible. Correct path to the source is: **ms-appx:///Assets\ActionIcons\like-action.png**. Why has it to be backslashes? I don't get it. 
But still, the different states for _hover_ and _pressed_ aren't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an initial slash is needed to accurately path the location of the image because the image is not *relative to the current xaml path*.

Change

`Source="Assets/ActionsIcons/like-action-on-pressed.png"`

to the *root of the package* with

`Source="/Assets/ActionsIcons/like-action-on-pressed.png"`

It does not look likes these are dynamic databound images. Dynamic images need `ms-appx:///` because they are not declared in xaml and need a special nomenclature to be properly pathed.

I believe the advice to add `ms-appx:///` works because it is providing a proper path which can be resolved, but is superfluous if a `/` is just added to the path.

---

For a better understanding read [How to load file resources (XAML) (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322(v=win.10).aspx)

Comment: It only works with the prefix `ms-appx/// ` 
My comment about the backslashes under the post above was nonsense because i had luckily solved another typing error. So far so good... 
Now I have a nice background image for the normal state.
And If i press (and hold) the button i've got a the other background image, but why is the image disappearing after releasing the button? I think more and more that I have to change the UI element from a `Button` to a `Checkbox` because i only want to do some background calculations which should be reversable when hitting the `Button`/`Checkbox` again...

Comment: HALELUJA... Finally. I was neither looking for a `Button` nor a `Checkbox`. The keyword was `ToggleButton`... Template in my question is also working for `TargetType="ToggleButton"`.

Comment: @Ulpin welcome to the multi-faceted world of Xaml. Glad you worked it out.